# ¿Se puede cambiar de masterpage en forma dinámica?

Tags: genexus, genexus15, genexusxev3

¿Se puede cambiar la Master Page de manera dinámica en los web panel de Genexus? ¿Cargar la Master Page que se desea según ciertas condiciones?

Comment: Ayudaria que comentes un poco que es lo que estas tratando de hacer, porque si bien no se puede cambiar la master page de forma dinamica por codigo, tal vez se puede lograr el comportamiento que estas buscando de alguna otra forma. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Segun la [documentación de Genexus](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8156,Master%20Page%20property), la propiedad MasterPage sólo aplica desde el IDE, no se puede cambiar en tiempo de ejecución:

*`This property applies only at design-time.`*